# Find a string in a table then copy the next cell to that value into another row

Tags: excel

I have been experimenting with some code but cant seem to get it to work. Thanks!

```
Sub c()

    Dim srchrng As Variant
    Dim cells As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

        For Each cells In srchrng
            If cells.Value = "Moisture Content" Then
                cells.Offset(0, 1).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Active.cell ("Q20")
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next cells

    End Sub
```

[image: 1]

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: "cant seem to get it to work" is not a helpful description, please state precisely the problem you are facing and any error messages.

Comment: Hi sorry about that, im trying to get excel to find one of result names and once it find the result name, i want it to offset the position by 1 to the right and take the figure and put it into a new cell, q20 to be precise. For example i would like excel to look through column g and then find "Moisture content" and then once it find moisture content it then to put the value for moisture content ("14") into Q20. this is so i can then copy and paste the row into another tracking sheet. thank for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim cells As Variant
For Each cells In [G2:G8]
        If cells = "Moisture Content" Then
            [Q20] = cells.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
Next cells
```

There's no need for `i`, the `For Each` loop manages the iteration for you.

Comment: Hi steve, thats work brillant thank you so much for your help. Max